# MINGW64 on Windows: print version

Tags: git-bash, mingw-w64

I have MINGW64 within Git Bash (from 64-bit Git 2.38.1).  How can I tell what version of MINGW64 I have?

Is there a command I can run to print the version?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a `git` option which would display that version, but knowing your version of Git for Windows, you can look for the matching [build-extra versions](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/tree/main/versions) file, like [`versions/package-versions-2.38.1-MinGit.txt`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/0b25881dffc7d1bd27d0138af8614b1dca969d6c/versions/package-versions-2.38.1-MinGit.txt#L48)

It shows: `msys2-runtime 3.3.6-1`, which would include [`MINGW-packages`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MINGW-packages). The latter changes regularly, but without any version or tag.

Comment: Ah gotchu. Since I have Git 2.38.1 from https://git-scm.com/download/win, you're saying just look at source files for that on GitHub and discern from there.  It's a decent workaround, thank you!

Comment: I wished there was something clearer, but for now, that is what I found.